# Rails 3 App Mysql2::Error - newbie can't write to db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying my first Rails3 app and am using the mysql2 gem. I can see my databases using sequel pro, but can't run "rake db:migrate"

I'm getting the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't create/write to file '/usr/local/mysql/var/inventory_development/schema_migrations.MYI' (Errcode: 2): CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Can anyone help interpreting this error? Thanks!

FWIW - I'm on Mac OS X / mysql 5.5.something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your MySQL data dir is incorrectly set. Check `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server` and set `basedir` and `datadir` appropriately. They probably should be

```
basedir=/usr/local/mysql
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
```

Then restart MySQL.

This problem is often why stopping/starting the server from the pref pane fails, too.

Comment: this was part of the problem. My .bash_profile was also set by Macports incorrectly